# Log4j2 + Java: add asyncLogger programmatically

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

So the question is how to add AsyncLogger dynamically in Java code?
What I want to get:

```
 <AsyncLogger name="io.example" level="info" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
 </AsyncLogger>
```

For sync loggers I usually use:

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
// creating logConfig
configuration.addLogger(packageName, loggerConfig);
```

but I can't find any "async" options. 
Maybe I should use another type of LoggerContext? Or use some specific type of LoggerConfig?

Also I want to have both "sycn" and "async" loggers, so setting all loggers as "async" in not an option for me.

Please help!

Comment: please read http://blog.takipi.com/how-to-instantly-improve-your-java-logging-with-7-logback-tweaks/. May help.